# Multiple versions of same JS library with Bower and django-pipeline

Tags: dependencies, frontend, bower, django-pipeline

Two of the libraries I use in my single page application are [moment](http://momentjs.com/) and [backgrid-moment-cell](https://github.com/wyuenho/backgrid-moment-cell).  I use [bower](http://bower.io/) to manage my front-end libraries and [django-pipeline](https://github.com/cyberdelia/django-pipeline) for asset packaging.

I'd like to use version 2.8.1 of moment, but backgrid-moment-cell requires version ~2.5.0.  How can I get both version into my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Front-end development should use a single dependency because you want to minimize the amount of code your users need to download. Bower helps you to manage this, which is a major benefit of using it. You have a few options:

- Manually namespace the modules then include both (really not recommended)
- Use [`resolutions`](https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec#resolutions) in `bower.json`, but you may introduce bugs:

```
"resolutions": {
    "moment": "2.8.1"
}
```

- Ask the maintainer to bump bower dependency versions (recommended)

Comment: I think the suggestion to bump the dependency is the best.  Although I do wish there was a way to handle dependencies on the frontend node-style where different libraries can load different versions.